# ms access - merge rows from two tables

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

After 5 years, I decided to change my old ms access database to a new design. I am facing a problem with merge/combine two tables in one. The tblapp is storing jobs done to customers(app_id, cust_id, app_date, app_price and job_id). The tblpay is storing payments(pay_id, cust_id, pay_date, pay_price).

These are my tables with the desire output table:

```
tblapp 
app_id   cust_id   app_date   app_price     job_id
  1         1     01/01/2000     500          1
  2         2     05/03/2002     200          2
  3         1     05/03/2002     100          1
  4         1     15/08/2007     300          2
  5         2     20/09/2011      50          2

tblpay
pay_id   cust_id   pay_date   pay_price
  1         1     01/01/2000     500
  2         2     05/03/2002     300
  3         1     20/08/2007     100
  4         1     20/09/2007     150
  5         1     22/10/2007      50
  6         2     20/09/2011      30
  7         2     25/09/2011      20

tbloutput <== Desire output table 
out_id   app_id   cust_id   out_date   app_price     job_id   pay_id   pay_price
  1         1        1     01/01/2000     500          1        1         500
  2         2        2     05/03/2002     200          2        2         200
  3         3        1     05/03/2002     100          1        2         100
  4         4        1     15/08/2007     300          2       
  5                  1     20/08/2007                  2        3         100
  6                  1     20/09/2007                  2        4         150
  7                  1     22/10/2007                  2        5          50
  8         5        2     20/09/2011      50          2        6          30
  9                  2     25/09/2011                  2        7          20
```

I would like base on date and cust_id to point payment to job_id. Each job_id must have one or more payments.

My problems are:
 - Two jobs where paid same day(different job_ids), but i stored one payment(total payment). Needto split and point to each job_id.
 - Many jobs where paid in the next months. So, all this payment must point again to a job_id.
 - Some jobs were paid half in the same day, and half in the future. Again, need to point to a job_id.

Any help from where to start.

Is it possible to point to a job_id or split payment and point.

My backup plan is to do it from the beginning all tblpay.
Hope to avoid not all but some rows, which i can safe point to a job_id.

Thank you.

Comment: *"After 5 years, I decided to change my old ms access database to a new design."* - Sure wish you'd changed it to a new design in e.g SQLServer! :)

Comment: @Caius_Jard First I will try to clean up a mess in old db.

Comment: @Caius_Jard  Then I will use MariaDB maybe. But if I don't point my data, I will not migrate soon, since I will have to do it one by one, 12000rows!!!

Comment: @Caius_Jard I can point the ones with same Date, Price and Cust_ID but it is only 2000rows...

Comment: @Caius_Jard Any help or idea that will make less work on one by one work, it is welcome.

Comment: What are the determinants and FDs in your new and old schemas?

Comment: What exactly is an 'app'? Your current payment table does NOT identify which job(s) or 'apps' payments were for. I don't think there is any query or code that can determine this for you. You will have to assess each payment and decide which job or 'app' to associate with. You have another table that associates customers with jobs?

Comment: @nicomp The tblapp is join with tblcust which is join with tblpay.

Comment: @ June7 No, I only use totals per cust_id. One sum from tblapp and one from tblpay. If I have a difference, then I have a debt. It was started simple but now it is a mess. It was only storing simple things.

Comment: My only idea, is to use OUTER JOIN and them filter by cust_id and ORDER BY date. then copy to excel and from there if I can make a formula to sum rows

Comment: The existing system could be workable - it's how your credit card works- payments are assigned to the oldest debts rather than to particular debts and then interest is charged on the most recent items not covered by a payment, if they're older than a certain amount. In a more powerful db I would probably have done this in a one using a query that totalled the payments and then for each payable in date order summed all the previous payables up to that one and compared with the total payments to see how much of the current payable has been paid

Comment: What benefit do you get from linking payments with apps?

Comment: @Caius_Jard I need to have each job with a payment. Need to know which job is not paid, or paid less. Now, I see only the debt.

Comment: you could try breaking the problem into parts.  if you only have a few problem records like the the 1 payment for two jobs just copy the problem records to paper and delete them from the old database.  Then it should be relatively simple to move the well formed records to a new database.  You can decide what to do with the problem records separately like adjusting the new database schema to handle 2 jobs with 1 payment.